# scroll bar style for WPF

Tags: wpf, styles

anyone know of a WPF scroll bar style that is out on the web that I can use instead of rolling my own, basically something like the Blend scroll bars would be cool. It would just save a lot of time if I didn't have to start from scratch. I know about this http://sachabarber.net/?p=122 but it isn't close enough to want I want. Like I said I could roll my own but it would save time if there was a pre-made example.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The link you included in your example does indeed style the scroll bar but it just isn't aesthetically pleasing to you and you want something nicer or are you looking for help in understanding the code in the link so you can achieve something nicer yourself?

Comment: I am looking for something that looks more like the scrollbar style in blend, essentially what I am saying is that I am lazy and don't want to start form scratch. It isn't a question of understanding it. It's a question of trying to save time.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a resource dictionary for scrollbar styles, that prominently exposes the colors. With this in place, I'm quick to adapt to a new style. The example below mimics the MS Outlook 2013 scrollbar.

[image]

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- this should better reside in a separate color resource dictionary-->
    <Color x:Key="White">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GrayUltraLight">#FFF2F2F2</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GrayLight">#FFD4D4D4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GrayMedium">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GrayMediumDark">#FF777777</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBrush" Color="{StaticResource White}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayUltraLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource GrayUltraLight}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource GrayLight}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayMediumBrush" Color="{StaticResource GrayMedium}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayMediumDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource GrayMediumDark}" />

    <!-- changing height/width of scrollbar -->
    <system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">15</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">15</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}">15</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}">15</system:Double>

    <!-- routing to base colors, but using new names in order to make changes easy -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="VerticalScrollBarBackground" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayUltraLightBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarBackground" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource VerticalScrollBarBackground}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarDisabledBackground" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayUltraLightBrush}}" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThumbBackground" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource WhiteBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThumbMouseOverBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayUltraLightBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThumbPressedBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayUltraLightBrush}}" />
    <Thickness x:Key="ThumbBorderThickness">1</Thickness>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThumbBorderBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThumbMouseOverBorderBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThumbPressedBorderBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumDarkBrush}}" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource WhiteBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonMouseOverBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource WhiteBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayUltraLightBrush}}" />
    <Thickness x:Key="ButtonBorderThickness">1</Thickness>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonMouseOverBorderBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumDarkBrush}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBorderBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumDarkBrush}}" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ArrowBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumDarkBrush}}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ArrowMouseOverBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumDarkBrush}}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ArrowPressedBrush" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GrayMediumDarkBrush}}"/>


    <!-- ScrollViewer (implicit style) -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarStyle1}"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarStyle1}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- Buttons (with arrows) -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="0">
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" Background="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThickness}"/>
                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Stretch="None" Data="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Fill="{StaticResource ArrowBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMouseOverBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMouseOverBorderBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ArrowMouseOverBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedBorderBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ArrowPressedBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- PageButtons -->
    <Style x:Key="VerticalScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Thumb -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThumbBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ThumbBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource ThumbBorderThickness}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThumbMouseOverBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ThumbMouseOverBorderBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThumbPressedBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ThumbPressedBorderBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- ScrollBar -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Content="M 0 3.5 L 3.5 0 L 7 3.5 Z" />
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Content="M 0 0 L 7 0 L 3.5 3.5 Z" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarDisabledBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarBackground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Content="M 3.5 0 L 3.5 7 L 0 3.5 Z"/>
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand}" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageRightCommand}" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                </Track>
                                <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"  Content="M 0 0 L 3.5 3.5 L 0 7 Z" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarDisabledBackground}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```